# Bootstrap Datetimepicker not displaying date in the text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Developing on ASP.net mvc 5, Bootstrap v3.3.7

In a Form I've a 'Date Of Calibration' field. I'm able to load bootstrap `datetimepicker` on this field on my Developing & Test machine. It's working fine there, but on the Live server the TextBoxFor date field doesn't show date inside it when the page loads. Once I click the textbox, datetimepicker appear and then the date gets rendered inside it.

I've also confirmed ViewModel does contain the date value when page is being loaded. It's just not getting rendered while page loads, and it only doing it on the production environment.

Any idea what could possibly be the reason

I'm loading Form inside a partial view in BootstrapModal.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date_of_calibration, new { id = "date_of_calibration", @class = "form-control" })
```

Loading `datetimepicker` as.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#date_of_calibration").datepicker({ format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'});}
```

Also loaded the following scripts inside the my partial view

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Update**

So before I was loading the field in the model as `model.date_of_calibration = DateTime.Now;` changed it to `= DateTime.Now.Date;` which uses only the date component of DateTime Instance.

Now the date does show up in the field when the page loads. but its doing it wrong. Interchanging "Date & Month". i.e If the database record has `2017-12-05 00:00:00.000 (i.e. 5th Dec)`, it show `12-05-2017 (i.e. 12th of May)` instead of `05-12-2017`.

Now again it's only happening on the live environment.

Comment: You haven't included `jquery.min.js` for one

Comment: No, I added jquery.js in the RegisterBundles() function in BundleConfig.cs

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? (and as a side note, you do not need `new { id = "date_of_calibration" }` - the `TextBoxFor()` has already added that attribute)

Comment: Does your server has the same regional settings of your local environment? What's your default date? Today? Do you have console errors? Any exception log?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not getting any error at all. The datetimepicker does load the calendar once clicked, It's just not showing the date inside the field that been passed by the ViewModel.

Comment: @JCM, There is 7 Hour difference, I'm ahead of my Live Environment. By default for this field I'm storing the current date as default while creating the model (model.date_of_calibration = DateTime.Now;).
And no mate, no special error on console.

Comment: Regarding your edit, use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.date_of_calibration, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })` to display the date in your format (but then your also going to run into other issues, including it will not bind correctly in the POST method unless your create a custom Model binder because that format does not match your server culture. You would also need to reconfigure the `$.validator` is you using client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code on your own html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Minified JS library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Minified Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="http://lisenme.com/demo/date_time_pick/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://lisenme.com/demo/date_time_pick/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
   
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Inline Datetime Picker</h1>
      <div id="datetime4"></div>
      
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#datetime4").datetimepicker();
      </script>
    
      <h1>Datetime Picker</h1>
      <input size="16" type="text" class="form-control" id="datetime" readonly>
 
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#datetime").datetimepicker({
       format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'
        });
      </script>

      <h1>Datetime Picker Auto Close</h1>
      <input size="16" type="text" class="form-control" id="datetime2" readonly>
 
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#datetime2").datetimepicker({
       format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
          autoclose: true
        });
      </script>

    </div>
  
  </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: What in the world does this have to do with the question (nothing at all - its not even using mvc!)